# How to browse and search Kafka messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, language-agnostic

Suppose I've got a server (a few server instances) that handles users requests in background and also produces `Kafka` messages: e.g. `handled successfully request X of user A`, `failed to handle request Y of user B`, etc.

I want to use these `Kafka` messages to:
a) notify users about their request status;
b) allow users to browse and search their request statuses: e.g. `find 10 last statuses of all requests X`.

Now I wonder how to implement (b). Can I search the messages using `Kafka` only without any database ? Should I consume the `Kafka` messages and copy them to a database ?

Comment: Have you tried to use a KTable grouped on X with a window of size 10? (Thus, yes, consume and copy data to RocksDB, as one solution)

Comment: Thanks. I just don't know what `KTable` is ... Could you add an answer to explain it a little ?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation/streams/core-concepts#streams_concepts_duality

Comment: Thanks. I will check it.

Comment: Overall, your question sounds very similar to the music application example, which stores top 5 genres of latest played songs - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.5.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/kafkamusic/KafkaMusicExample.java#L335

Comment: Yes, it sounds similar. I just want to understand the basics. Is it correct that `KTable` API works against `Kafka` storage and I don't to need deploy/install anything in addition to our regular `Kafka` deployment ?

Comment: That's correct. It creates internal, compacted topics for managing state stores

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's probably the answer I need :))